# How to attach widgets from html attribute values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, hook

I want to do the following:

1. declare applicable widgets, e.g. like this: `$.fn.myWidget = function(options) { ... }`
2. define in html which widget to apply to the element: `<div widget="myWidget">some text</div>`

In case when I don't insert code dynamically, to implement such thing is almost trivial:

```
$(function() {
  $('*[widget]').each(function() { $(this)[$(this).attr('widget')]() })
})
```

But when a code insert dynamically (e.g. from AJAX), we need to traverse that new code as well. So there are two questions:

1. Is there a plugin, library or something that solve my wider problem (e.i. take widget name from html attribute and initialize the widget for that element)?
2. Is there some functionality that allows handle (hook) cases when jQuery inserts html elements dynamically (using .html(), .prepend(), .load() etc)?

**update: more details**

Partially it's possible to solve problem using the following approach:

```
$.fn.applyWidgets = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    var $e = $(element);
    var widget = $e.attr('widget');
    if(widget) $e[widget]();
  });
}

$.fn.htmlWithWidgets = function(html) { 
  this.html($(html).applyWidgets());
}
```

and then use `$(selector).htmlWithWidgets(html)` instead of `$(selector).html(html)`

Still it would be interesting to learn how to intercept html() and similar calls and apply the approach implicitly, "from inside".

Comment: Tomalak, could you elaborate what is wrong with my tags?

Comment: Nothing. But tags go in tags; don't repeat them in the title please.

Comment: So, the idea is that tag summarize the context and title summarize the content. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! :) Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Seems like what you looking for is a **server side** "control" - kinda like ASP.NET controls.

Comment: liho1eye, Nope. I talking here about client-side components.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I end up with the following solution:

```
  var _widget_bindings = {}

  // registers css_class and associates with widget_initializer callback
  function bind_widget(css_class, widget_initializer) {
    if (jQuery.fn[css_class]) throw "widget with name "+css_class+"already defined";
    _widget_bindings[css_class] = widget_initializer;
    jQuery.fn[css_class] = widget_initializer;
  }

  // for each element in set takes DOM subtree and for each element in the subtree with registered css_class
  // invokes corresponding widget_initializer
  jQuery.fn.init_widgets = function() {
    this.find('*[class]').andSelf().each(function() {
      if (!this.className) return;
      var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
      for (var i = 0, l = classes.length; i < l; i++) {
        var css_class = classes[i];
        if (css_class && _widget_bindings.hasOwnProperty(css_class))
          _widget_bindings[css_class].apply(jQuery(this));
      }
    })
    return this;
  }

  // invokes a method (can be .html(), .append(), .prepend(), .before(), .after()) by given method_name
  // and initializes widgets for newly created elements
  jQuery.fn.with_widgets = function(method_name, elements) {
    var j_elements = jQuery(elements);
    this[method_name](j_elements);
    j_elements.init_widgets();
    return this;
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function() { (document.body).init_widgets() })
```